# Restart application automatically on KILL

Tags: objective-c, macos, process, finder

I am developing an application on MAC OS . It needs to run continously i.e. if someone kills it , it has to restart on its own . I found a similar behavior in the Finder application in MAC. How can I implement this ???

Currently, I am using launchctl for this purpose  but I am facing some problems with permissions and communication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`launchctl` is the way to do it.  In order to get it set up, you need to understand about authorization services.  [The Authorization Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995) is a good place to start.

Comment: I did try this with launchctl . But there was an issue. My application actually has 2 parts , a daemon (which needs to be continuously running) and a UI element. Now I need these to communicate with each other . I am using distibuted objects for the same (as given here http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Base/ProgrammingManual/manual_7.html) . But whenever I use launchtl to launch the daemon , communication fails . Can you please suggest something ???

Comment: @ping localhost: that's a whole other issue.  I suggest you ask another question to cover it.